# Can't get Scrapy pipeline to work

Tags: python, web-crawler, pipeline, scrapy, scraper

I have spider that I have written using the Scrapy framework. I am having some trouble getting any pipelines to work. I have the following code in my pipelines.py:

```
class FilePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open('items.txt', 'wb')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = item['title'] + '\n'
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

and my CrawlSpider subclass has this line to activate the pipeline for this class.

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = [
        'event.pipelines.FilePipeline'
    ]
```

However when I run it using

```
scrapy crawl my_spider
```

I get a line that says

```
2010-11-03 20:24:06+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines:
```

with no pipelines (I presume this is where the logging should output them).

I have tried looking through the documentation but there doesn't seem to be any full examples of a whole project to see if I have missed anything.

Any suggestions on what to try next? or where to look for further documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it! The line needs to go in the settings module for the project. Now it works!

Comment: No, my client may have put it up somewhere, but not my place to open source it I'm afraid.

Comment: i had to use ITEM_PIPELINES as a dict instead of a list in the settings file

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet that it's a capitalisation difference in the word pipeline somewhere:

Pipeline vs. PipeLine

I notice `'event.pipelines.FilePipeline'` uses the former, whereas your code uses the latter: which do your filenames use?

(I have fallen victim to this spelling mistake many times!)

Comment: Thanks for spotting that (can't believe I missed it!), but it still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: It's still my bet at what's wrong, keep checking! :P (if not, I'm out of ideas...)

Comment: I'll have another look. Cheers!